# Neo4j - How do I get elapsed query cypher time in the REST API with Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

How do I get elapsed query cypher time in the REST API with Neo4j? (I need a field with the query time)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exposed directly from the Neo4j REST API, however you can measure it on the client side (which of course will show the http overhead). Using python and py2neo for example:

```
import time
from py2neo import Graph

db = Graph()

def query():
    start = time.time()
    db.cypher.execute("MATCH (a) RETURN count(a);")
    end = time.time()
    print("Query took: " + str((end-start)*1000) + " ms")
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I am doing this, but it counts the network time. I want the query elapsed time directly from REST API.